# Detect click on border of widget in tkinter 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a kind of movable widget program in python with Tkinter, but I ran into a problem. I can't detect a click without interfering with the function of the widget that you click on. (example: Text or Button widget)

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
main = tk.Tk()
notes = tk.Text(main, height = 15, bd = 4)
notes.place(y = 10, x = 20)
notes.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: print("hello"))
```

But if you try and click in the middle, it still works. Is there any way to make it only clickable on the border and not the widget itself?

Comment: So, you want to completely disable the widget and _only_ support moving the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default behavior by returning `"break"` from the event handler. For example:

```
def hello(event):
    print("hello")
    return "break"
...
notes.bind("<Button-1>", hello)
```

The same works for any widget. This prevents the default behavior (moving the cursor, clicking the button) from happening.

Another choice is to put each widget in a frame with a small border, and then put the binding on the frame.